# New Aviation Site Design!

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design

Good news everyone, it was discussed on the Stack Exchange podcast, and [we now have a site design](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22625824#22625824). This should be rolling out as soon as we can get the design spec converted into workable CSS.

Completed layout:

[image]

If you have any comments before this is finalized, please let me know.

<sub>Design contributed by Stack Exchange user [HarryCBurn](http://stackexchange.com/users/3716393/harrycburn).</sub>

Comment: Better than most sites, great work! :D

Comment: WTF?!!?!!??!! :D

Comment: Also, it should be [featured], not [status-bydesign]

Comment: @bjb Thanks! It took several hours for me to craft my masterpiece.

Comment: ...what? No unicorns?!

Comment: @vore I felt like the unicorns (which were now removed) added too much fun to an otherwise extremely, *extremely*, serious site.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the podcast which mentioned Aviation.SE.  Do you know the time stamp?  Does this mean that we've graduated?  ;-)

Comment: @Lnafziger was listening to it on livestream. I'll post a link when the recording is released, for posterity sake.

Comment: I will be the happiest man alive if this is implemented. It won't, but it should be.

Comment: Well, no oftense great design but it is hard to make the site looks SERIOUS with this. Again, i welcome all new ideas ;)

Comment: @vasin1987 Are you saying serious? These sorts of designs have become a trend on other SE sites! For example... http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/a/387/69

Comment: @HarryCBurn Nice job on the design!  I may have to see about getting you to design my next snailplane.

Comment: @snail Hah! Sure, but my services don't come cheap!

Comment: I simply *need* this piece for my collection... How much do you want for it? Three million?

Answer (score 13):

As the author of the work, I can offer a harsh (although biased) opinion on the matter.

The piece speaks to me, in that the singular turbine, whilst inhibiting flight, can both continue to fly, progressing through issues as Aviation.SE does.

Similarly, I feel as though the "Kneawwww" text also contributes to one of the main aspects of the site: free speech in a controlled way. This also shows the hand-crafted network through the hand-written text.

The whole feel of the picture shows the running motifs of AV.SE, and should be used as prime promotional material for not only AV.SE, but also for the SE network in general.

Thanks for reading my critic!

Comment: can you make the logo pop?

Comment: Will edit when I have the time ;p

Comment: @Jin I know a guy who can do prints on mylar balloons. You're on your own for inflating it until it pops :-)

Comment: (no offence) but a so less serious design might deceive new users about the strict moderation exercised here, and cause an increase in low-quality posts.

Comment: I don't really expect new users to devote their time in understanding "Kneawwww".

Comment: @gochobot When *will* they learn, dammit?

Comment: Can you make the blue a little more *blue*.

Answer (score 8):

I think that on the [4th of July](http://d2vo5twcnd9mdi.cloudfront.net/uploads/45ff870a-9817-4e66-9b71-209804072238-Independence-Day-1996-%E2%80%93-Hollywood-Movie-Watch-Online.jpg), the Aviation.SE airplane should crash into the [Arqade](http://www.arqade.com/) mothership.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PirVtiJuvDs

[image]

Comment: Remember This - [How do we prevent a predominantly US focus?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74/how-do-we-prevent-a-predominantly-us-focus/140#140)

Comment: @anshabhi Remember This - [Aviation **is** US-centric](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13102033#13102033)  :)

Answer (score 8):

Looks good, I approve.

[image: Perfection]

Comment: Is that photoshop or is that real?

Comment: @Zizouz212 It's real, I just edited things through "Inspect Elements" in Firefox.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't.

Comment: @ans If I could downvote a comment, I would! The design is clearly amazing.